I want to remove a particular column from a file, basically it should be passed as null using Python (not using dataframe)
I have a .dat file which has a description column that contains text with commas, semi-colons, and double quotes. The inner double quotes are causing a problem while loading the data to temp table. So, I just want to eliminate the column from the file or not load any data from that column.
I am looking for a Python program that can help me remove inner double quotes (using replace function) or using pop/del to remove that column from that file.
See my code below, which has issues removing the column
import os
import csv
import sys

from shutil import copyfile

sourcedir=sys.argv[1]
sourcefile=sys.argv[2]
targetdir=sys.argv[3]
targetfile=sys.argv[4]
qualifierIN=sys.argv[5]
delimiterIN=sys.argv[6]
qualifierOUT=sys.argv[7]
delimiterOUT=sys.argv[8]


curDir = os.getcwd()
sep = os.path.sep

if  os.path.exists(sourcedir):
    print("Source Directory : {x}".format(x=sourcedir))
    os.chdir(sourcedir)
    if os.path.isfile(sourcefile):
        print("Source File : {x}".format(x=sourcefile))
    else:
        print("Source File Not Found : ", sourcefile)
else:
    print("Source Directory Not Found : ",sourcedir)
    sys.exit(5)



if  os.path.exists(targetdir):
    print ("Target Directory : {x}".format(x=targetdir))
else:
    print ("Target Directory Not Found :",targetdir)
    os.makedirs(targetdir)

try:
    with open(sourcefile, 'rt') as fin:
        reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=delimiterIN, quotechar=qualifierIN )
        os.chdir(targetdir)
        with open(targetfile, 'wt') as fout:
            writer = csv.writer(fout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, quotechar=qualifierOUT, delimiter=delimiterOUT)

            try:
               for row in reader:

                    index = 0
                    for field in row:
                        row[index] = str(row[index].replace(delimiterOUT, ""))   # delimiter
                        row[index] = str(row[index].replace(qualifierOUT, ""))   # qualifier
                        row[index] = str(row[index].replace(';', ""))             
                        row[index] = str(row[index].replace('"', ''))            # unix newline
                        #row[index] = str(row[index].replace('\r\n', ""))        # windows newline
                        
                        index += 1
                    print(row)
 
                    writer.writerow(row)
            except csv.Error as e:
                print("Error: ", str(e))
                sys.exit(25)
            finally:
                fout.close()
                fin.close()
                os.chdir(curDir)
except Exception as e:
    print("Error : ", str(e))
    sys.exit(35)



try:
    os.chdir(sourcedir)
    os.remove(sourcefile)
    copyfile(targetfile, sourcefile)
  except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
    sys.exit(45)

sys.exit(0)

Data sample from the file:
Header:
invoice number,invoice date,vendor number,vendor site ID,supplier site CODE,invoice description,invoice currency code,invoice total amount,line number,line amount,line description,account code,business unit,business center,department,issue code,project,task number

Input:
315,1992-02-14,2501,641,PHIL,PRINT INT' T,USD,117,75,71,"PAN - RETRIEVE AND REVIEW REPORT FOR "LIFE LOGO" IN CLASS (2029- 17) RE: REGISTR FEB 8, 2024; REPORT TO CLIENT AND REQUEST INSTRUCTIONS TO PROCEED; UPDATE RECORDS AND  ACTION IN DATA.",6400,5951,51820,1172,08,,

Output after running the above program:
"315","1992-02-14","2501","641","PHIL","PRINT INT' T","USD","117","75","71","PAN - RETRIEVE AND REVIEW REPORT FOR LIFE LOGO IN CLASS (2029- 17) RE: REGISTR FEB 8","2024; REPORT TO CLIENT AND REQUEST INSTRUCTIONS TO PROCEED; UPDATE RECORDS AND ACTION IN DATA.""","6400","5951","51820","1172","08","",""
"

Issue:
The life logo text double quotes are now removed but "2024; REPORT TO CLIENT AND REQUEST INSTRUCTIONS TO PROCEED; UPDATE RECORDS AND ACTION IN DATA." is shifted to the next column in the database table.
I just want to remove this entire line description column from the file.
So, I just want to remove this entire line description column from the file, and just replace null or '' in the place of line description for all the rows in the file.

Could you please [edit] to indicate what precise output you expect for your sample? Is it 315,1992-02-14,2501,641,PHIL,PRINT INT' T,USD,117,75,71,,6400,5951,51820,1172,08,, or something else?

Removing inner quotes
It is a good task for a regular expression(s).
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html
This expression removes only paired quotes that are not next to a comma in non-edge columns:
r'(,[^,]+)"([^,"]+)"([^,]+,)'

Here is a link to a popular regex website which includes an explanation of what the regular expression does. [Added by edit]
regex101.com demo
Application:
import csv
import os
import re
import sys

INNER_QUOTES_MID_COLUMN_REGEXP = re.compile(r'(,[^,]+)"([^,"]+)"([^,]+,)', )

...

try:
    with open(sourcefile, 'rt') as fin:
        with open("/".join(targetdir, targetfile), 'wt') as fout:
           for row in fin:
               ...
               row = INNER_QUOTES_MID_COLUMN_REGEXP.sub(r"\1\2\3", row)
               ...

               print(row)
 
               print(row, file=fout)
...


Just replace column with null
import csv
import os
import re
import sys

...
try:
    with open(sourcefile, 'rt') as fin:
        reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=delimiterIN, quotechar=qualifierIN)
        with open("/".join(targetdir, targetfile), 'wt') as fout:
            writer = csv.writer(fout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, quotechar=qualifierOUT, delimiter=delimiterOUT)

            try:
               for row in reader:
                   ...
                   row[10] = "null"
                   ...

                   print(row)
 
                   writer.writerow(row)
...


Thank you Nick. I am having an issue with  row = INNER_QUOTES_MID_COLUMN_REGEXP.sub("\1\2\3",row)
^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Also, any idea on how to just replace that particular column for all the rows with null instead of regular expression

Why do you think that's "instead of" regular expression? The regex is used to find the problematic data; if you want to replace it with just a comma instead of nothing, obviously do that instead.

the business requirement is so. They don't want to populate that column. The vendor is charging more to change their file format. So, they want to remove that column from a file or pass null values to that field.

"IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level ". You need to check number of leading spaces in this line. If you do not know what is "indentation" then it would be a great help to read more about Python in English because it save you much time and other stuff might be much harder.

"Also, any idea on how to just replace that particular column for all the rows with null instead of regular expression" Regular expression has much more power to ignore it. But I have added one more solution that is more suitable for this request. (Please, do not forget to accept the answer if it helped ;) )

A link to regex101.com with your regex and test cases would be much preferred over a screen shot, please.

@tripleee As I said, I do not know the policy regarding pasting such links, and I pasted the regex separately, and the test case is "input data" from the question.

I replaced the image with a link, but the regex is not working properly for this example; I guess you would want [^,"] instead of just [^,] throughout.

row[10]=null worked but there is an issue again with one line wherein the description has commas within and that is being considered as next column value and regex is not working it says - ('Error : ', 'expected string or buffer')

[^,"] will cause problem if some other " exists in between

can you help me remove the commas in that column which causing a major problem please!

i tried the regex link that you have shared, it says pattern error- (,[^,]+)"([^,"]+)"([^,]+,)

Try this instead https://regex101.com/r/ssjnBG/1

"regex is not working it says - ('Error : ', 'expected string or buffer') " It was not regex, but I guess I fixed.

"there is an issue again with one line wherein the description has commas within" csv reader must be able to overcome it, if the configuration is right. With regexp it is harder to overcome this case and maybe some tweaking is needed

does this need to be passed with anything else - INNER_QUOTES_MID_COLUMN_REGEXP.sub("\1\2\3", row). Where is the fix? @Nick

Here is a simple script to remove any column which contains unquoted literal quotes.
import sys
import re

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as lines:
    for line in lines:
        while m := re.match(r'^((?:(?:[^,]*|"[^"]*"),)+)(?:"[^"]+(?:"[^"]+"[^"]+)+",)(.*)', line):
            line = m.group(1) + m.group(2)
        print(line, end="")

You'd pass it the name of the input file as a command-line argument, and it will produce the modified file on standard output.
python script.py problematic.csv > fixed.csv

Demo (modified to read from standard input): https://ideone.com/iz9tV5
The regular expression has three main components;

^((?:(?:[^,]*|"[^"]*"),)+) matches valid fields with no internal double quotes in them, one or more. The outermost parentheses capture the match into group 1. (The other (?:...) parentheses are non-capturing.)
(?:"[^"]+(?:"[^"]+"[^"]+)+",) matches (but does not capture) one field with embedded double quotes somewhere within it. It copes with repeated sequences of embedded double quotes, as long as they are properly paired.
(.*) captures the remainder of the line into group 2.

As long as the regex matches, we replace the line with just the captured groups, removing one problematic field at a time, until the regular expression no longer matches. (If it never matched in the first place, we simply copy the line unmodified to the output.)
